# AdoQuery filter disables StringGrid-Edit Function

Tags: delphi

I have some TEdits that are linked to an AdoQuery and this one to a StringGrid. So, when I change the selection in the grid, the Edits change it's contents too, and get the data from the selected cell. This is automatic, without any code line.
 But when I filter the AdoQuery, with the `AdoQuery.Filtered` property, this automatic thing doesn't work, and the Edits get only the first cell values.
 How can I filter the AdoQuery and keep this StringGrid-Edits link working?

Edit: I've added an image of the issue, as you can see, the edits remain with the values of the first record even with the second selected. Ignore the others column, only that two are in test.

[image: Exemple]

Comment: This is using live bindings, correct?  Also what  exactly do you mean by " only the first cell values"?  Do you mean only the cells in the first column of the grid are displayed, or that the cells only show the original field values, not any values you might have changed?

Comment: Yes, I'am using live bindings. Only in the first line of the grid, and each column is a field like name,phone,etc. Let's suppose that there are 10 records on the table, and using the filter only two are showed. When I select the grid line that refers to the second record, the Edits don't change it's values to match with it, they just keep the same as the first record, even if the selection is different. The edits doesn't change it's values to match the ones in the grid. But when the filter is disabled, it works normal.

Comment: Ok, I'll see if I can reproduce that a bit later today.  A screenshot of the problem in your q would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the example code below, which is a self-contained example of a
ClientDataSet connected via LiveBindings to some TEdits and a TStringGrid, with
a facility to impose a filter on the value in a named TField.  I've also included
the relevant part of the DFM so that you can see the Live Bindings.

The project includes a standard TDBGrid connected to DataSource1, to compare its
behaviour with the TStringGrid.

Leaving aside the filtering issue, just compile and run the project.  Using Delphi
Seattle, what I see in the StringGrid is no row with ID = 5, but two rows with
ID = 6, which is clearly wrong.  The DBGrid shows the rows correctly, including
ID = 5.

Moving through the StringGrid using the DBNavigator, the edID, edName and edValue
TEDits display the correct values even though the StringGrid does not.  If I
start editing the Name column of the first row with ID=6 using the edName TEdit, the
StringGrid immediately corrects itself to show row ID=5 instead of the first ID=6 one.

So there seems to be something wrong with live bindings in this simple project, even without getting into filtering.  I find that the problem I've described does not occur if the IndexFieldNames property of the ClientDataSet is set to 'ID;Name'.

However, despite the above quirk, filtering using the edFilterFieldName and
edFilterValue TEdits seems to work fine, and does not seem to show the problem
you say you are having.  I've used a ClientDataSet so that I could generate
some test data in the project's code.  However, I can't immediately see why
there would be a problem with filtering an AdoQuery in a similar way.

Code

```
TForm1 = class(TForm)
  StringGrid1: TStringGrid;
  DataSource1: TDataSource;
  edFilterFieldName: TEdit;
  edFilterValue: TEdit;
  Memo1: TMemo;
  CDS1: TClientDataSet;
  CDS1Name: TStringField;
  CDS1Value: TStringField;
  edName: TEdit;
  edValue: TEdit;
  BindingsList1: TBindingsList;
  CDS1ID: TIntegerField;
  DBGrid1: TDBGrid;
  edID: TEdit;
  LinkControlToField1: TLinkControlToField;
  BindSourceDB1: TBindSourceDB;
  LinkControlToField2: TLinkControlToField;
  LinkControlToField3: TLinkControlToField;
  LinkGridToDataSource1: TLinkGridToDataSource;
  DBNavigator1: TDBNavigator;
  procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  procedure edFilterFieldNameChange(Sender: TObject);
  procedure edFilterValueChange(Sender: TObject);
  procedure CDS1NewRecord(DataSet: TDataSet);
private
  FFilterFieldName : String;
  FFilterValue : String;
  procedure SetFilterFieldName(const Value: String);
  procedure SetFilterValue(const Value: String);
  procedure UpdateFilter;
public
  NextID : Integer;
  property FilterFieldName : String read FFilterFieldName write SetFilterFieldName;
  property FilterValue : String read FFilterValue write SetFilterValue;
end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i : Integer;
begin
  // AutoPost := True;
  CDS1.IndexFieldNames := 'ID';
  CDS1.CreateDataSet;

  for i := 1 to 6 do begin
    CDS1.Insert;
    CDS1.FieldByName('Name').AsString := 'Name  ' + IntToStr(i);;
    CDs1.FieldByName('Value').AsString := 'Value  ' + IntToStr(i);
    CDS1.Post;
  end;

  CDS1.First;
  StringGrid1.Invalidate;
  FilterFieldName := edFilterFieldName.Text;
  FilterValue := edFilterValue.Text;
end;

procedure TForm1.CDS1NewRecord(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  Inc(NextID);
  DataSet.FieldByName('ID').AsInteger := NextID;
end;

procedure TForm1.edFilterFieldNameChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FilterFieldName := edFilterFieldName.Text;
end;

procedure TForm1.edFilterValueChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FilterValue := edFilterValue.Text;
end;

procedure TForm1.SetFilterFieldName(const Value: String);
begin
  if FilterFieldName <> Value then begin
    FFilterFieldName := Value;
    UpdateFilter;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.UpdateFilter;
var
  Expr : String;
begin
  if CDS1.FieldByName(FilterFieldName) = Nil then begin
    CDS1.Filtered := False;
    exit;
  end;
  CDS1.DisableControls;
  if FilterValue <> '' then begin
    Expr := FilterFieldName + ' like ' + QuotedStr('%' + FilterValue + '%');
//    Expr := 'substring(FilterFieldName, 1, 1)' + ' = ' + QuotedStr(FilterValue);
    Memo1.Lines.Add(Expr);
    CDS1.Filter := Expr;
    CDS1.Filtered := True;
  end
  else
    CDS1.Filtered := False;
  CDS1.EnableControls;
end;

procedure TForm1.SetFilterValue(const Value: String);
begin
  if FilterValue <> Value then begin
    FFilterValue := Value;
    UpdateFilter;
  end;
end;
```

Partial DFM

```
object DBNavigator1: TDBNavigator
  Left = 600
  Top = 208
  Width = 240
  Height = 25
  DataSource = DataSource1
  TabOrder = 8
end
object DataSource1: TDataSource
  DataSet = CDS1
  Left = 128
  Top = 24
end
object CDS1: TClientDataSet
  Aggregates = <>
  Params = <>
  OnNewRecord = CDS1NewRecord
  Left = 72
  Top = 24
  object CDS1ID: TIntegerField
    FieldName = 'ID'
  end
  object CDS1Name: TStringField
    FieldName = 'Name'
    Size = 40
  end
  object CDS1Value: TStringField
    FieldName = 'Value'
    Size = 80
  end
end
object BindingsList1: TBindingsList
  Methods = <>
  OutputConverters = <>
  Left = 128
  Top = 88
  object LinkControlToField1: TLinkControlToField
    Category = 'Quick Bindings'
    DataSource = BindSourceDB1
    FieldName = 'ID'
    Control = edID
    Track = False
  end
  object LinkControlToField2: TLinkControlToField
    Category = 'Quick Bindings'
    DataSource = BindSourceDB1
    FieldName = 'Name'
    Control = edName
    Track = False
  end
  object LinkControlToField3: TLinkControlToField
    Category = 'Quick Bindings'
    DataSource = BindSourceDB1
    FieldName = 'Value'
    Control = edValue
    Track = False
  end
  object LinkGridToDataSource1: TLinkGridToDataSource
    Category = 'Quick Bindings'
    DataSource = BindSourceDB1
    GridControl = StringGrid1
    Columns = <
      item
        MemberName = 'ID'
      end
      item
        MemberName = 'Name'
      end
      item
        MemberName = 'Value'
      end>
  end
end
object BindSourceDB1: TBindSourceDB
  DataSource = DataSource1
  ScopeMappings = <>
  Left = 216
  Top = 32
end
```

Comment: Ok, this is great and worked well this way. But because of my lack of knowledge in Delphi, my previous filter was made simpler than this( only in one procedure, and because I made it in Firemonkey,somethings are different, so I don't get it very well).I rethinked my project and choose to do the filter with the SQL propertie in the AdoQuery and I worked well and even changed the TEdits at the same time as I wanted. Maybe I've misspelled somethings and when I said "Edits" I've mean TEdits. But your solution worked Great anyway. If you want the project to take a look I would gladly send it to you